# Minimize with Interval restriction

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

If for instance I have a problem of this sort:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR]1 = Interval[{0, 1}];
gigi[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := With[{go = 2},
  dfe=a + b^2 + b + d^2 + e + f^2;
  a + dfe+go
]

FindMinimum[{gigi[a, b, c, d, e, f], a \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]1}, 
 {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 
 StepMonitor :> Print["Step to x = ", a]
]
```

Why doesn't it accept that "a" must belong to the region defined as an interval?

Comment: A few things are unclear to me in your code: 1) is `dfe` supposed to be the product of d,f and e? Or is it a single variable, in which case is it defined elsewhere in your code? `FindMinimum` is a numerical function, so it can't deal with symbols with undefined value. 2) What is `go` supposed to do in your definition of `gigi`? Perhaps you could clean up your code to show only what is relevant to your current problem, I.e.  a minimal working example.

Comment: Ok, I'll clean it up quick.

Comment: Anyhow this is just an example. I had to write it down as I can't post my real problem because it is uselessly too complicated.

Comment: Mirko, I think the long and short of it is that `FindMinimum` only appears to work with constraints expressed as equations or inequalities ([KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)); for instance, in your simplified case `0 <= a <= 1` works fine.

Comment: Does NMinimize work only with Karush Kun Tacker conditions too?

Comment: `NMinimize` should work with constraints expressed as regions: it's one of the syntax examples shown in its documentation.

Comment: MarcoB indeed! I tried running the examples over other types of regions and it works.